# Determine if text has been selected that may be cut or copied to clipboard

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

My app has menu items for cut, copy and paste. I know how to execute these actions but not how to determine if something has been selected. I need to know this to enable or disable the cut and copy menu items (which I would do in `TAction.OnUpdate` events).

For example, to copy selected text from the currently focused control, I use this:

```
if Assigned(Focused) and TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXClipboardService, Svc) then
  if Supports(Focused.GetObject, ITextActions, TextAction) then
    TextAction.CopyToClipboard;
```

But, how do I determine if any selection of text has been made in the currently focused control?

I could iterate through all my controls and use conditions like this:

```
if ((Focused.GetObject is TMemo) and (TMemo(Focused.GetObject).SelLength > 0) then 
  <Enable the Cut and Copy menu items>
```

but this does not seem elegant. Is there a better way?

EDIT:

Based on Remy's answer, I programmed the following and it seems to work:

```
procedure TMyMainForm.EditCut1Update(Sender: TObject);
var
  Textinput: ITextinput;
begin
  if Assigned(Focused) and Supports(Focused.GetObject, ITextinput, Textinput) then
    if Length(Textinput.GetSelection) > 0 then
      EditCut1.Enabled := True
    else
      EditCut1.Enabled := False;
end;
```

`EditCut1` is my `TAction` for cut operations, and `EditCut1Update` is its `OnUpdate` event handler.

EDIT 2:
Following Remy's comment on my first edit, I am now using:

```
procedure TMyMainForm.EditCut1Update(Sender: TObject);
var
  TextInput: ITextInput;
begin
  if Assigned(Focused) and Supports(Focused.GetObject, ITextInput, TextInput)
    then
  EditCut1.Enabled := not TextInput.GetSelectionRect.IsEmpty;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TEdit` and `TMemo` (and "all controls that provide a text area") implement the [`ITextInput`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Text.ITextInput) interface, which has [`GetSelection()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Text.ITextInput.GetSelection), [`GetSelectionBounds()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Text.ITextInput.GetSelectionBounds), and [`GetSelectionRect()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Text.ITextInput.GetSelectionRect) methods.

Comment: Guided by your answer, I adopted code as shown in the edit to my question and it seems to work.

Comment: @Duns: Your second `if` can be eliminated: `EditCut1.Enabled := Length(Textinput.GetSelection) > 0;` This might also work too, without having to allocate memory for a temp `string`: `EditCut1.Enabled := not Textinput.GetSelectionBounds.IsEmpty;` or `EditCut1.Enabled := not Textinput.GetSelectionRect.IsEmpty;`

Comment: It does indeed seem that my second if can be eliminated. And my if else can be rewritten as `EditCut1.Enabled := Length(Textinput.GetSelection) > 0;`.     `EditCut1.Enabled := not Textinput.GetSelectionRect.IsEmpty;` also works. Strangely, `EditCut1.Enabled := not Textinput.GetSelectionBounds.IsEmpty;` does not seem to work as it never seems to return true.